# SQL Server Agent logging actions and changes done to jobs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, jobs

Is there a way to track changes done to SQL Server Agent jobs?

If you had a reason to believe somebody is playing around with your job settings. How would you proceed to track who did it and from where the changes were made to the individual job?

I'm thinking along the lines of extended events.

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: 2014 enterprise

Comment: Well, I would say SQL Audit might work for you...but just tried a few test and it does not work like I thought it would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For sake of simplicity, I will assume that you want to track sysjobs, sysjobsteps and sysjobschedules. There may be other tables you want to monitor.

**Option 1: SQL Audit (requires Enterprise Edition)**

```
USE [master]
GO

-- Audit
CREATE SERVER AUDIT [jobs]
TO FILE 
(   FILEPATH = N'PathToSomeFolder'
    ,MAXSIZE = 0 MB
    ,MAX_ROLLOVER_FILES = 2147483647
    ,RESERVE_DISK_SPACE = OFF
)
WITH
(   QUEUE_DELAY = 1000
    ,ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE
    ,AUDIT_GUID = 'e807469a-6c9d-43f1-af46-cf7b89ba898d'
)
ALTER SERVER AUDIT [jobs] WITH (STATE = ON)
GO

USE [msdb]
GO

CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [job_changes]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [jobs]
ADD (UPDATE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[sysjobs] BY [public]),
ADD (UPDATE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[sysjobsteps] BY [public]),
ADD (UPDATE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[sysjobschedules] BY [public])
WITH (STATE = ON)
GO
```

The data captured by the audit appears like this:
[image: SQL Audit]

**Option 2: Extended Events session**

```
-- Step 1: extract object_id for the following tables
SELECT object_id 
from sys.tables
WHERE name IN ('sysjobs','sysjobsteps','sysjobschedules');

-- Step 2: use those object_ids in the following session:
CREATE EVENT SESSION [capture_job_changes] ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.lock_acquired (
    SET collect_database_name = (0)
        ,collect_resource_description = (1)
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name, sqlserver.is_system, sqlserver.server_principal_name)
    WHERE (
        [package0].[equal_boolean]([sqlserver].[is_system], (0)) -- user SPID
        AND [package0].[equal_uint64]([resource_type], (5)) -- OBJECT
        AND [package0].[equal_uint64]([database_id], (4))  -- msdb
        AND (
               [object_id] = 1125579048 -- sysjobs
            OR [object_id] = 1269579561 -- sysjobsteps
            OR [object_id] = 1477580302 -- sysjobschedules
        )
        AND (
               [mode] = (8) -- IX
            OR [mode] = (5) -- X
        )
    )
)
WITH (
     MAX_MEMORY = 20480 KB
    ,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE = ALLOW_MULTIPLE_EVENT_LOSS
    ,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY = 30 SECONDS
    ,MAX_EVENT_SIZE = 0 KB
    ,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE = NONE
    ,TRACK_CAUSALITY = OFF
    ,STARTUP_STATE = OFF
);
GO

-- Step 3: add a convenient target to the session (file target?)
```

The data in the XE session appears like this:
[image: XE session]

Regarding this second option, I wrote a blog post on a similar subject ([tracking object usage](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/20/tracking-table-usage-and-identifying-unused-objects/)) where I describe the details of the technique. Basically, you can consider IX/X locks as updates to the underlying tables.

This session captures the bare minimum, but you can add more fields/actions to it to capture the sql text or the computer name or whatever makes sense for you.

Comment: a couple years late to the party, but looking at doing this as well.  Thanks!  (Nice blog post; looking through that powershell implementation, too - pity that histogram doesn't work better, since that would be the easy way). Was wondering why you chose to monitor the tables as opposed to the stored procedures like sp_update_job.  Thanks!

Comment: Excellent point. Auditing the procedures would probably be enough to capture changes from SSMS. Even if unsupported, you can still change the tables directly.

Comment: Just a note that 'Step 1' of the XE session needs to run in the context of msdb