# Is there a date modified timestamp for steps in a job on msdb?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, jobs

I need to figure out which steps have been modified since the beginning of the month. I can find which jobs have been modified, but some of the jobs have 20+ steps, so knowing which specific step was modified would be very useful.

This is where I found the job/step msdb info: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2561/querying-sql-server-agent-job-information/

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/120579/1186

Comment: @AaronBertrand If I'm reading that correctly (I'm still a beginner so bear with me) it's a way to monitor the steps going forward. So I would have to set it up and wait for it to fill with data before it is useful?

Comment: That’s right. SQL Server simply doesn’t track step modifications by default. You can’t go back in time and set up a video camera to catch someone stealing a package off your porch, but you can set it up now and catch the next person.