# Something is mysteriously diabling our transaction log backups

Tags: sql-server

One of our servers is getting the SQL Server Agent job that does transaction log backups **disabled** with no apparent reason. It has happened sporadically, twice in the last 30 days or so, precisely after 3:00 AM. So, the question is: Has anyone ever experienced specific SQL Server Agent jobs being disabled spontaneously like this? (It's obvious *something* is disabling the job automatically.) Does anyone have any theories why/how this would happen? Any insights appreciated. Best, Raphael.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things to look at, but what I would to first is, enable an extended event or a SQL Audit that captures the events related to SQL Server Agent jobs.

There is already a good question about that on here:

[SQL Server Agent Logging Actions and Changes done to Jobs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120579/sql-server-agent-logging-actions-and-changes-done-to-jobs)

And also check for last modified date:
`select name , enabled , date_modified from msdb.dbo.sysjobs where enabled = 0`